# Ignore characters up til whitespace after matching character with regex

Tags: regex

I have a string

```
fw[0000]: IN=br1 MAC=00:80:00:00:00:8b SRC=0000::0000:000:0000:0000 DST=0000::1:2 LEN=179 PROTO=UDP DPT=547 Unsolicited IPv6 Packet
```

and would like to extract the last section of the message so that the resulting capture is

```
Unsolicited IPv6 Packet
```

I am using this current regex string `([^=]*$)` which gets me

```
547 Unsolicited IPv6 Packet
```

but I am stuck on how to exclude the `547`  from the capture group. In other words, capturing everything after the final equal sign while excluding the content that is in between the equal sign and the first space in front of it.

The `547`  is just an arbitrary value here. Another log line may have `PROTO=UDP` as the final key/value pair prior to the ending message text.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: This will be used in a Graylog extractor, which uses the Java engine for regular expressions.

Comment: Try [`.*=\S*\s*(.*)$`](https://regex101.com/r/f0vSTu/1/)

Answer (score 1):

If your tool or language has access to regex capture groups, then you may phrase your regex as consuming everything up, and including, the final key=value pair:

```regex
^.*\b[^=\s]+=[^=\s]+\s+(.*)$
```

### Demo

The match you want would appear as the first capture group `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use "positive lookbehind":

```
(?<=\s)([^=]*)$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/khlo0M/1/).

This works as follows: `(?<=Y)X`, matches `X`, but only if there’s `Y` before it.

In this case `[^=]*` matches from the final `=` to the end of line but only the part which preceded by the first space.

Keep in mind - your original regex `([^=]*$)` won't work as expected, when message text contains `=`.

Answer (score 0):

You could match the equals sign and the first "word" after it followed by a space (or `\s+` for 1 or more whitespace chars)

```
=[^\s=]+\s+([^=]*$)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bFfLad/1)

Another option is too match until the last equals sign followed by matching the first "word" and 1 or more whitespaces.

Capture in group 1 matching at least single non whitespace char followed by matching the rest excluding an equals sign.

```
^.*=[^=\s]+\s+(\S[^=]+)$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5dYYI5/1)